# Mapbox GL JS : Distance Measuring - KM to MI display

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I am working on a project where I will be using the "measure" tool located in the Mapbox GL JS API (example with code is at the following link).

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/measure/

I am currently using that code as a base, but until I incorporate it into my project and make custom s I realized it measures in KM and not Miles. Is there a way to have the value to be returned in miles that I am missing? I have looked my best through the resources I have but unable to find anything. At worst I would have to write javascript but I am not the best with it yet, so I hope I can get some guidance here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use the latest version of the turf library: http://turfjs.org/getting-started

2) Use the length function with the units option:

```
var line = turf.lineString([[115, -32], [131, -22], [143, -25], [150, -34]]);
var length = turf.length(line, {units: 'miles'});
```

[ http://turfjs.org/docs#length ]